# Left join selecting with linq and a condition

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

I'm trying to select with linq a left join to find all products that have never been ordered more than 50 at a time. I'm not sure what is wrong.
This is what I did but I'm not getting the right answer.

This is my code:

```
var q5 = from p in db.Products
                 join o in db.Orders on p.ProductID equals o.OrderID
                 join od in db.Order_Details on o.OrderID equals od.OrderID
                 where od.Quantity < 50
                 select p.ProductID;
        foreach (var p in q5)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(p);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find products which were  **never** be ordered more than 50 at a time. So a join to orders doesn't help much. You could use this approach:

```
var productsWithLowOrders = db.Products
    .Where(p => !db.Orders
        .Any(o => p.ProductID == o.OrderID && db.Order_Details
            .Any(od => o.OrderID == od.OrderID && od.Quantity >= 50)));
```

This query is using `Enumerable.Any`, in SQL it'll be translated to subqueries to the related tables using `NOT EXISTS` + `EXISTS`.

Comment: @coco: i don't see the problem. What is the exact message?

Comment: @coco: there was a missing colon before `Where`, [fixed it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37411222/revisions)

Comment: How do I select the Products?

Comment: @coco: it already selects products. `db.Products.Where(...)`. You don't have any products which were not ordered with `Quantity >= 50`. Try to change the value to `>=500`. Perhaps then you see some products

Comment: So why this is what i'm getting " Finish_Linq_queries_from_class_4.Product "

Comment: @ TimSchmelter: how we get the name of the Product? I'm getting this " Finish_Linq_queries_from_class_4.Product "  foreach one

Comment: Just use `foreach(Product p in productsWithLowOrders) Console.WriteLine(p.Name);`

Comment: It gives me all the Products and not only the selected in the condition

Answer (score 0):

So this is the best solution I found:

```
var q5 = from p in db.Products
                 from od in db.Order_Details
                 .Where (od => od.ProductID == p.ProductID)
                 .Where (od=> od.Quantity > 50).DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select (od.OrderID !=null ? "-" : p.ProductName)
                 ;
        foreach (var p in q5)
        {
            if(p != "-")
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(p);
            }   
        }
```